# ListView list is reversed when selection made

Tags: java, android, listview, reverse

So I had my listview working perfectly then I decided to add a context menu. As soon as I did that whenever I normal clicked an item in my listview, the entire list gets inverted on the first click. Subsequent clicks do nothing to the order, but when the first item is de-selected again the list returns to normal. When I take out the context menu logic that I added, the list view problem does not go away.

I've attached a debugger and the elements in my list adapter are never reordered, and the ListView itself is never set to reverse with `.setStackFromBottom()`

Here is my onClick listener registered to handle the click events of the list view items:

```
public void onClick(View v) {  
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();  
    CheckBox b = holder.box;  
    Boolean check = b.isChecked();  
    b.setChecked(!check);  
    if (!check) {  
       mChecked.add(holder.fu);  
       if (mChecked.size() == 1) {  
         buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
       }  
    } else {  
       mChecked.remove(holder.fu);  
       if (mChecked.size() == 0) {  
         buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
       }  
   }  
}
```

The viewholder class just holds references to objects I use in the listview for optimizations. I cannot figure out why this is causing my list to invert when displayed, I've tried moving the listener to a different view in the layout, I've tried re-writing the listener, nothing seems to work! Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: here is the code for the view holder

```
/** Class to provide a holder for ListViews. Used for optimization */  
private class ViewHolder {  
    TextView date;  
    TextView gallons;  
    TextView cost;  
    TextView cpg;  
    TextView mpg;  
    CheckBox box;  
    FillUp fu;  
}
```

as well as the adapter:

```
 public class FillUpAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<FillUp> mElements;
        ArrayList<FillUp> mChecked;
        Context mContext;

        public FillUpAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<FillUp> data) {
            mContext = c;
            mElements = data;
            mChecked = new ArrayList<FillUp>();
        }

        public void clearChecked() {
            mChecked.clear();
        }

        public ArrayList<FillUp> getChecked() {
            return mChecked;
        }

        public boolean remove(FillUp f) {
            mChecked.remove(f);
            return mElements.remove(f);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mElements.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return mElements.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return mElements.get(arg0).getId();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout layout;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView != null) {
                layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
            } else {
                layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.fillup_list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.cost = (TextView) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpListTotalValue);
                holder.cpg = (TextView) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpListCostPerGal);
                holder.gallons = (TextView) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpListGalValue);
                holder.mpg = (TextView) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpMPGText);
                holder.date = (TextView) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpListDate);
                holder.box = (CheckBox) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.fillUpListCheckBox);
                holder.fu = (FillUp) getItem(position);
                layout.setTag(holder);

            }

            holder.date.setText(holder.fu.getDate());
            holder.gallons.setText(holder.fu.getGallonsText());
            holder.cpg.setText(holder.fu.getCostText());
            holder.cost.setText(holder.fu.getTotalText());
            holder.mpg.setText(String.format("%03.1f MPG",holder.fu.getMPG()));
            if (convertView != null) {
                holder.box.setChecked(mChecked.contains(holder.fu));
            }

            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    CheckBox b = holder.box;
                    Boolean check = b.isChecked();
                    b.setChecked(!check);
                    if (!check) {
                        mChecked.add(holder.fu);
                        if (mChecked.size() == 1) {
                            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mChecked.remove(holder.fu);
                        if (mChecked.size() == 0) {
                            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return layout;
        }
}
```

UPDATE:
Ok, so I've narrowed it down to the visibility change on the buttonLayout view, which is a linear layout of buttons on the bottom of the Activity's layout, underneath the ListView. Whenever I change that view's visibility to `View.VISIBLE` (which happens when the first item is checked) the list's order is reversed. The order is restored when the view's visibility is set to `View.GONE`

I have no idea what would cause that though :(

Comment: Probably something in your Adapter, check that code

Comment: Yes, problems with symptoms like this almost always indicate an Adapter bug.

Comment: Show us the code for the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After narrowing the scope a bit more, I discovered the problem was not the changing of the visibility of my button bar, but actually the passing around of `FillUp` objects in `holder.fu` of my `ViewHolder` class. By changing that to instead reference the adapter's `getItem(position)` method, everything seemed to work out.  Quite an odd bug, since the adapter itself was not having the order of the elements changed, but passing around a reference to the object made it very unhappy.

Answer (score -1):

If your listview background color changes when you click on it, I think it is about your theme. Just play with the cache color parameters of your listview, here is an example:

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="all"
            android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:paddingTop="115dip">
</ListView>
```

Comment: The colors are not changing, only the order in which the list is ordered.