# onCheckedChanged changes LinearLayout setVisibility reverses ListView items order

Tags: java, android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have an Activity with an ListView of CheckBox and TextView items. When I first check or last uncheck a CheckBox I want a LinearLayout with some buttons to show/hide. That works ok. The problem is that whenever that happens the ListView items order get reversed. That behavior only happens when I have no checkbox selected and check one or when I have a last selected an uncheck it.

My Adapter getView code is as follow:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)view;
    ViewHolder holder;        

    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)container.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.serverlist_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.serverlist_checkbox);

        holder.textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serverlist_name);

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)container.findViewById(R.id.buttons_linearlayout);
                int visibility = View.VISIBLE;

                if (isChecked)
                {
                    nChecked++;
                }
                else
                {
                    nChecked--;

                    if (nChecked == 0)
                    {
                        visibility = View.GONE;
                    }
                }

                layout.setVisibility(visibility);

            }
        });

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

    holder.textview.setText(hostname);

    return v;

}
```

If I comment out **layout.setVisibility(visibility)** the problem disappears. I've already checked this post [ListView list is reversed when selection made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725892/listview-list-is-reversed-when-selection-made) but I could not get my code to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks